# update Activity Score on Contact and Account

Tags: apex, trigger, community

I want to calculate Activity Score on Contact and Account should be updated based on following formula.

```
Contact/Account Activity Score = 
Count of Meetings * 3 + Count of calls * 2 + Count of Emails * 1
```

*Note: This count will be done separately for all child activities of Account/Contact records!*

can you please let me know how this can be implemented 
i am thinking to write trigger on task and event object

please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

Don't write your own rollup code - it's time-consuming and tricky to cover all of the different contingencies.

Install [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) instead. You can define three rollups on each object for counts of meetings, calls, and emails, and then write a formula field to calculate your score.

Make sure you're aware of the distinction between an Activity's [`AccountId` and `WhatId`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194177&language=en_US&type=1) and decide which one you want to roll up accordingly.